# Wave equation - initial displacement is box function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

> Solve the equation $u_{tt} = u_{xx}$ where the initial displacement is $u(0,x) = 1$ for $1<x<2$ and 0 otherwise. Also the initial velocity is 0.

I am not too sure how to go about this. I know d’Alembert’s formula, which tells us that $u(t,x) = \frac{f(x-t) + f(x+t)}{2}$, so the wave separates into two left and right travelling waves that superimpose (I think?).

However I cannot find an explicit formula for $u(t,x)$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is the explicit formula if $f$ is the initial function.

Comment: @Andrew yes, but I cannot determine what f is with this initial displacement and use it find a formula for $u$

Comment: Well $f$ is the step which is described in the condition: $1$ for $1<x<2$ and zero elsewhere.

Comment: @Andrew ok, but I want $u$...

Comment: Write $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ into the wave equation. you will end with two independent ODEs from which you can solve, using your initial dispalcement information at the outset.

Comment: One needs to express $f$ for that. Is that explicit enough? $f(x)=\theta(x-1)\theta(2-x)$ where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function.

Answer (score 1):

Using the initial condition at $t=0$,

$u(0,x)$ = $\theta(x-1)-\theta(x-2)$

and defining $b(x)=\theta(x-1)-\theta(x-2)$

where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function,

then $u(t,x)=b(x-t)/2+b(x+t)/2$

which are two 'box' functions traveling right and left.